# reading a matrix column by column at the same time as the second matrix, numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 2 matrices. The first matrix is traversed by each column and each column is assigned a 2nd matrix as shown in the example
Below is an example only. I need for matrices of different dimensions

```
import numpy as np
arr1=np.array([[11, 21,31], [12, 22,32], [13, 23,32], [14, 24,34]])
arr2=np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

I need

```
 # 1st column from arr1
    11 1
    12 2
    13 3
    14 4
#2nd column from arr1
    21 1
    22 2
    23 3
    24 4
#3th column from arr1   
    31 1
    32 2
    33 3
    34 4
```

I tried different options.
For example, this even from pre-prepared my result was this

```
print(*(f' {i} 0\n'.join(s.split() + ['']) for s, i in zip(arr1.splitlines(),arr2.split())), sep="")
```

my result

```
11 1 
21 1 
31 1 
12 2 
22 2 
32 2 
13 3 
23 3 
33 3 
14 4 
24 4 
34 4
```

I tried this too but it didn't work

```
osem = np.vstack([ np.c_[arr1[:,x], arr2[:,y]]
        for x, y in np.c_[np.triu_indices(n=arr.shape[1], k=1)] ]
```

Comment: Based on what you wrote here, I have no idea what you are asking. The sentences "Gradually, in order to traverse column by column in the matrix and then to each column from the 1st, the matrix assigned the 2nd matrix. It doesn't matter what the dimensions of the matrix are" seem nonsensical to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below is very specific to your use case.  I'm not sure if there is a larger problem you're trying to solve.  But given arr1 and arr2 from your example, you could use the following code

```
a = np.zeros((arr1.flatten().shape[0],2)) #init the new array
a[:,[0]] = arr1.T.flatten()[:,None]  #fill the first column with the values
a[:,[1]] = np.tile(arr2,3)[:,None]  # fill the second column with values
a
>>>
Out[39]: 
array([[11.,  1.],
       [12.,  2.],
       [13.,  3.],
       [14.,  4.],
       [21.,  1.],
       [22.,  2.],
       [23.,  3.],
       [24.,  4.],
       [31.,  1.],
       [32.,  2.],
       [32.,  3.],
       [34.,  4.]])
```